# What kind of attack is a request like this?

Tags: sql-injection

The number of request strings like this one seems to have increased over the last weeks. They all have in common, that they contain a combination of google adwords / google adsense parameters and sql injection.

The decoded value of the request string is

```
/?gclsrc=aw.ds&gclsrc=aw.ds& and 1>1
```

I can see

- a duplicate gclsrc parameter
- an sql injection attempt

... but why this combination? Is it a technique to grab adsense revenues while sqli probing?

Comment: The first part is called HTTP Parameter Pollution (HPP) and the second part a SQL injection in order to generate one or more errors. HPP can be used to bypass web application firewalls (which in this scenario is not the case)

Answer (score 1):

This could be an initial control test for blind AW injection.

Typically those start with a true/false test.

So perhaps they are testing `1>1`, which is always false.

Then they will also test `1=1`, which is always true.

And look for a difference in the response

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Blind_SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information here to answer. Most attacks aren't something you can identify from just one code snippet like this; attributes of the target system, as well as the surrounding traffic from the same host matter a whole lot more.

In fact, just based on the information provided, my opinion (YMMV) is there isn't enough to say with certainty that it's even malicious.